# Javascript compare date give me wrong result

Tags: javascript

I just want to compare two dates but it give me the wrong result and I cannot find why... Any idea ?

```
> (new Date("2017-11-25"))
Sat Nov 25 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
> new Date(new Date().toDateString())
Fri Oct 27 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
> (new Date("2017-11-25")) < new Date(new Date().toDateString())
false
> (new Date("2017-11-25")).getTime() < (new Date(new Date().toDateString())).getTime();
false
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is normal, we are in october. Maybe you want to compare with `2017-10-25` instead of `2017-11-25`.

Comment: Yes x) I think i'm tired... I just found my mistake with snapjs answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be working fine to me.  What result are you expecting?

```js
console.log((new Date("2017-11-25")).getTime() < (new Date()).getTime()); // false
console.log((new Date("2017-10-25")).getTime() < (new Date()).getTime()); // true
```

Comment: I want to kill myself... I just was wrong with the month... (typed 11 (nov) instead of 10 (oct))... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm? What wrong results are you seeing? Javascript is outputing the correct result.

Check the first date is highter than the second date.

The sing "<" is a condition that mean "lower to"...